# Can SQL float column used to save C# double value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, casting

I have a double variable in my code, after doing some calculation I need to save this number to a SQL float column, but when the code executes, the following exception appears:

```
double value = expression.calculate();

point = new Point
{
    DefinitionId = definition.Id,
    Time = day,
    Value = value
};

_context.Points.Add(point);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

[image]
[image]

Should I round the value before saving it?

**Update:**

The following is the Point class:

```
 public class Point
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int DefinitionId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DefinitionId")]
        public Definition Definition { get; set; }

        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

        public double Value { get; set; }

    }
```

This is the value when the exception happened:

[image]

**SQL Version**:13.0.4001.0

**.Net Entity Framework**: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.2

Comment: What does `class Point` look like

Comment: The question is not whether you should round, because it depends on the accuracy your application requires. Whether you have to convert your double to float? Yes.

Comment: @TheGeneral Updated

Comment: @PepitoSh all I need is saving the  double value to DB coulmn, Is there  need to convert it before doing that?

Comment: Yes. Or alternatively you can change your data definition in the database.

Comment: @PepitoSh thank you, what is the equivalent to C# double in SQL Database?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 Maybe float(25)?

Comment: funny how SQL server emits this elaborate essay of an error message, when all you need is "you passed a double for @p2 which expects a float".

Comment: Can you change your Point class to use `float` as datatype for that Value?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing as the following article, we should use SQL Float for C# doublehttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

Comment: A `FLOAT` column is a double-precision floating point type that can hold all values C# stores in a `double`, with the notable exception of denormal numbers. The number in the screenshot is not a denormal number, so this should work. What version of SQL Server, what version of .NET/Entity Framework? You may also want to hook up a profiler to see if you can see anything interesting in the `RPC:Starting` event (if it even starts).